# Tricky convergences of harmonic series divided into digit-9-contained denominators and digit-9-not-contained denominators?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

(It's hard for me to summarize the problem precisely with the title...)

The harmonic series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ is not convergent as we all know. Now I partition the series into 2 series, one consisted of denominators containing digit 9 in decimal form and the other consisted of the rest entries, as follows:
$$
\sum{b_n}=\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{19}+\frac{1}{29}+\cdots +\frac{1}{90}+\frac{1}{91}+\cdots +\frac{1}{99}+\frac{1}{109}+\frac{1}{119}+\cdots ,
$$
$$
\sum{c_n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{10}+\cdots +\frac{1}{88}+\frac{1}{100}+\cdots 
$$
I need to prove that $\sum b_n$ is not convergent while $\sum c_n$ is. I've merely got an intuitive idea: As the number of digits of denominator increases, the digit-9-contained denominators appear more frequently and the digit-9-not-contained denominators appear less frequently. To show this, one only need to consider the probability of a digit-9-not-contained denominator of n-digit, approximately $(\frac{9}{10})^n$, which goes to $0$ when $n$ goes to infinity.

However, this is only a rough and intuitive idea and I don't know how to prove it in a quantitative and rigid manner. Any help would be aprreciated!

Comment: @player3236 I think so, thanks a lot!

Comment: $\sum c_n$ is called [Kempner Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kempner_series) and it converges. Using this fact and the fact that the harmonic series diverges, we can see that $\sum b_n$ must diverge.

Comment: While the Kempner series converges, it does so very slowly. Just in case you want to know: the sum is approximately $22.9206766192641503$. ;-)