Convergence of a series using only the n's with no units digit 9
Here is a question from an exam I just took.
Let $p$ be a real number that is greater than $\log_{10}{9}$. Prove that the series is convergent.
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}=\frac{1}{1^p}+\frac{1}{2^p}+\dots+\frac{1}{8^p}+\frac{1}{10^p}+\frac{1}{11^p}+\dots+\frac{1}{18^p}+\frac{1}{20^p}+\frac{1}{21^p}+\dots$
Note that this series uses only the $n$'s with no digit 9.
My attempt was to note that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\log_{10}9}}$. Using the Direct Comparison test, I only needed to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\log_{10}9}}$ was convergent. Moreover, I expressed the series as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n^{\log_{10}9}}-\frac{1}{(10n-1)^{\log_{10}9}}\right)$. However, the integral test showed that this series was divergent.
Is there another way to go about it?

What do you need to prove on this series? Also does $1/90^p$ appear in the sum (or do you just erase the one with unit digit $9$)? Thank you in advance!

Well my first question received an answer with your last edit, thank you for that.

You need to count the number of $n$ with no nine with $10^k<n<10^{k+1}$, $k=0,1,2,\dotsc$ as a first step.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4053724/tricky-convergences-of-harmonic-series-divided-into-digit-9-contained-denominato and the questions linked to it.

Making any progress? Thought about my comment? Checked out my link?

Yes, @GerryMyerson. I think I've gotten the hang of it. The sum of the series should be less than $\frac{8}{1-(\frac{9}{10})^p}$ , which converges since  $p> \log 9$. This also shows why my solution (direct comparison test) wouldn't have worked.

Good. Why not write that up in detail, and post it as an answer? Alternatively, if you're convinced that your question is a duplicate of one of those older questions, leave a comment to that effect, and we can commence procedures to close your question as a duplicate (or, if you feel such action is justified, you can simply delete your question).

Let $S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^p}}$.
The plan is to find a sum larger than S and show that it is convergent. To clarify an earlier question, when we say "this series uses only the $n$
's with no digit 9", we also mean to exclude terms that have 9 in their $k$th digit.
There are 8 1-digit numbers, $8\times9$ 2-digit numbers and $8\times9\times9$ 3-digit numbers. In general, there are $8\times9^{k-1} k-$digit numbers.
So, $S<8\times\left(\frac{1}{1^p}\right)+8\times9\times\left(\frac{1}{10^p}\right)+8\times9\times9\left(\frac{1}{100^p}\right)+\dots$
The right hand side of the inequality is an infinite geometric series with common ratio $r=\frac{9}{10^p}$. Since $p>\log 9$, $10^p>9 \implies \frac{9}{10^p}<1$. So, the right hand side converges to $\frac{8}{1-\frac{9}{10^p}}$.
Therefore, S converges.

I think you mean the series converges only if $9/10^p < 1$. Ie the common ratio is $9/10^p$

+1. But please add a definition of $r$ before you present conclusion regarding $r$ being less than $1$.

@SBK thanks for catching that.

@CiaPan, yes that seems more sound. reflected that in the edit. hope that's better. thanks.
